# How to monitor subprocess's stdout in real time

Tags: python, subprocess, stdout

I have a subprocess that generate images. A main programe will consume images.

My plan is to launch subprocess, monitor it. Once there are several images available *(i.e. subprocess printed '2' or '3')*, I will start main programe.

However, I fail to get 'real-time' output from subprocess. Every time, subprocess will not return anything via PIPE until it has generated all 20 images. Except in debug-mode.

in `sub_process.py`:

```py
import time
for i in range(20):
    time.sleep(1)
    print(i)
    # generate one image each second
```

main process: ready to go on processing images if there is at lease one image.

```py
from subprocess import PIPE
from subprocess import Popen

p= Popen(['python', "./subprocess.py"], stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE) 

while True:
    if '2' in p.stdout.readline().decode("utf-8"):
    print('enough image')
    break
print('go on processing images generated by subprocess.py')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add `flush=True` in subprocess.py as parameter to `print`:

```
import time
for i in range(20):
    time.sleep(1)
    print(i, flush=True)
    # generate one image each second
```

Note: if you name your file `subprocess.py`, then on your other program your subprocess import will fail, because it tries to import from your `subprocess.py`, not from the actual subprocess library.

I recomand puting a `p.kill()` on the end to stop your image generator